# How to upload case related file in redhat support portal

Tags: python, redhat

I want to upload files using programmatically(like python) after given red-hat support case (as described in https://access.redhat.com/articles/5594481)
I am able to generate token using given end-point https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/v2/sftp/token .
Could someone please suggest how to upload file in given case-id

Comment: You should probably open a support ticket for this with Red Hat directly... I am not sure how well StackOverflow can help dealing with specific vendor's systems.